# MySQL DUMP Extra caracters when execute shell scrip

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, sh

I want to do a cron that will run SH script to dump mysql table.
But I notice that when I run the script, there are extra caracters on file or directorie created.
I want to create every day a directorie and put export in.

Here is my script

[image: Here is my script]

It's look normal on Ftp

[image: Ftp]

But on shell I can see the extra caraters

[image: Shell]

Do yo have an idea of why this please ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The sh script was Windows Format instead of Unix format. I edited it on windows machine before upload it to linux server so I just change the format in Notepad ++.